# How do I operate on highlighted text in VI/VIM?

Tags: vim

I want to know how to do some operations on highlighted lines (with v operator) like providing tab to selected line, comment those line, etc. using vi/vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most standard operations that require a motion also work in visual mode, so if you select something in one of the visual modes (v, shift-v or ctrl-v), you can indent a line with the `>` key, comment those lines by **pressing** `:s@^@# @` (which will show `:'<,'>s@^@# @` on the command line as the visual range is entered automatically).

Another way of commenting out blocks is to select them with the column visual select (ctrl-v) and press `I` to insert at the start of the line.

```
:help v_>
:help visual-start
:help :s
:help I
```

There are also a couple of plugins [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23) and [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=955) that help with commenting.  If you want any more specific information, please can you make your question a bit more detailed as it's difficult to tell what you really want at the moment.

Comment: these kind of extra trik which will reduce the work effort using VI and make it easy for you to work.

Answer (score 5):

For indenting the selected portion of code, you can use the **=** command to do it automatically, or you can use the **>>** and **<<** commands to increment or decrement the indenting.

Also another useful command, **gv**,  you can use it to recover your last selection.

Comment: +1: gv is one I didn't know: very good, thanks.  You can also just use :'<,'>s again and it will remember the last selection.